# Is it possible to upgrade Linux Mint 13 to 18?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I'm using `Linux Mint 13 Mate` for quite some years now. It is `based on Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome` but `LTS` is about to be expired as it is `till 26 Apr 2017`).

I would like to upgrade to the most current version which is `Linux Mint 18` which is `based on new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.

Is it possible to do a `direct upgrade` skipping all the versions in between or do I need to upgrade to 14, then to 15 etc.?